# C# Unity dictionary use key to open a .csv file

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, foreach

**SOLUTION:**
Use the .Trim() function of C# to delete whitespaces in the dictionary.key or .value function!

I use Unity and program in C#.

The issue is that I wanna use the string key of a dictionary to open a csv file with the same name (see code). The issue is that it does not work. C#/Unity get the right Key, as a string with the right text and all, however, it cannot find the file.

E.g.: if I just type "start/Germany" or use a variable with that name it works.
If I use "start/" + var.Key it does not, although it is exactly shown as "start/Germany".

EDIT:
To clarify again: Unity is not able to find the file when I use ("start/" + country.Key), but it does when using "start/France" or any other country. In the log it is shown as exactly the same "string"/path. When I delete the try exception it gives:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I checked many different combinations of if statements, nothing gives a TRUE statement...

```
if(("start/" + country.Key) == ("start/France"))
if(("start/" + country.Key).Equals("start/France"))
if(("start/France").Equals("start/" + country.Key))
```

....

However it seems that the string as a Key in the dictionary is used as a normal string in text but the comparison of that string with a normal string is always false. The strings ARE the same in the dictionary!

```
 public class LoadData : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static void Load(string filename)
        {
            TextAsset dataFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Data/" + filename);
            string[] data = dataFile.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

            string[] columnHeader = data[0].Split(new char[] { ';' });

            Debug.Log("Load <" + filename + ">");
            //Debug.Log("The source file has " + data.Length + " rows");

            for (int i = 1; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                string[] row = data[i].Split(new char[] { ';' });

                // Skip the row if the first cell of a row is empty
                if (row[0] != "")
                {
                    if (filename.Contains("start"))
                    {
                        LoadStartVariables(row);
                    }
                    else if (filename.Equals("countries"))
                    {
                        LoadCountries(row);
                    }
                    else if (filename.Equals("global"))
                    {
                        LoadGlobalVariables(row, columnHeader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void LoadStartVariables(string[] row)
        {
            Debug.Log(row[0] + " = " + row[1]);
        }

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateNewGame
{
    public static void StartNewGame()
    {
        LoadData.Load("countries");
        InstantiateCountries();
        LoadData.Load("start/France");
        LoadData.Load("start/Germany");
        LoadData.Load("global");
    }

    private static void InstantiateCountries()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Country> country in Global.countries)
        {
            //LoadData.Load("start/" + country.Key.ToString());
            try
            {
                LoadData.Load("start/" + country.Key);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log(country.Key + ": No File!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What "does not work" ? Is there an error? Where exactly does it break down?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes. He explained that the file cannot be found if he uses `country.Key`, resulting in an exception that he catches: "...however, it cannot find the file..."

Comment: @Zimano I still don't see any mention of an exception.

Comment: You could try checking if `"start/France" == "start/"+country.Key" if that's true, and the TextAsset loading is still different, then you have found a bug in Unity. If it is false, you have the wrong strings in your dictionary.

Comment: @Crowcoder It is obvious that a file not found will throw an exception in this case. The problem is quite clear to me after reading the code and their explanation.

Comment: It is odd that you are using a key as the data instead of the value. Are you mixing them up somehow?

Comment: Are you even sure you're getting an IOException?  Try removing the try/catch block and debug the exception manually for a second.

Comment: Thanks for your statements. Check the edited part in my post. Is it maybe an issue of static functions?

Comment: Have you checked for whitespace characters in the key? Try Trim()in them.

Comment: Perfect. After some tries it worked! Thank you very much.